# PowerBi Gateway Issues

Tags: powerbi, gateway, powerbi-datasource, onpremises-gateway, powerbi-gateway

I am trying to set up a PowerBi Gateway which was there already but was pointed to a different VDI. Now since that VDI is corrupt, I deleted the older gateway connection, and installed the gateway in the new VDI machine. I am able to see a gateway connection from my new VDI datasets page. But when I select the VDI machine and give 'Apply', it shows the following message and asking me to contact Support. Please help how to resolve this.